Concatenate and separate column values, if they exist
I have a table with 3 columns which may or may not have values ​​separated by a comma. For example:



Column_1
Column_2
Column_3




A

C



D, E
F


A
X
Z




Z



Basically, the result I am looking for is that the following cell contains, for each case:
[X]A, [X]C
[X]D, [X]E, [X]F
[X]A, [X]X, [X]Z
[X]Z
Being [X] a fixed value that I add to each case.
Is it possible to do it with a standard Excel formula?

A Join-Split-Join

=LET(data,A2:C11,delimiter,", ",prefix,"X",
    dp,delimiter&prefix,
    BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        j,TEXTJOIN(delimiter,,IF(ISERROR(r),"",IF(r="","",r))),
        IF(j="","",prefix&TEXTJOIN(dp,,TEXTSPLIT(j,delimiter)))))))


Try using the following one single dynamic array formula:


=BYROW(A2:C5,LAMBDA(α,
 LET(δ, CONCAT(α&", "),
 TEXTJOIN(", ",1,"[X]"&TEXTSPLIT(δ,", ",,1)))))


Explanations:

Using BYROW() function which applies a custom LAMBDA() calculations to each row in the array to return one single array as output.
So, the custom function applied here, within a LET() function, which helps in reducing the redundant calculations as well, reduces the use of repeated formulas.
Variable δ  is defined to CONCAT(α) all the cells in the rows into one by a delimiter comma.
Next, we are splitting the same using TEXTSPLIT() function by columnwise and ignoring the blanks which may or may not return.
Finally, wrapping within the TEXTJOIN() function to wrap the whole with a delimiter comma and a space, along with the splitted output a fixed value [X] has been joined to get the desired output as one single array.


Also, without using the LAMBDA() helper function, could use the following to copy it down :
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,"[X]"&TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(TOROW(A2:C2,1)&", "),", ",,1))



Another way using Office 365:
=ARRAYTOTEXT("[X]"&TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(TOROW(A1:C1,1)),", "))


I wasn't aware of the following ARRAYTOTEXT's 'shortcoming': its delimiter consists of the Excel's List separator and a space i.e. if one's List separator is a semicolon (;), the formula doesn't work.

Nice to know, @VBasic2008. I do think - since OP uses the comma as delimiter in his sample - that comma would be the separator, but thanks for posting this. I wasn't aware.
